# Intellij IDEA does not import dependencies from gradle and don't mark src dirs

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What does my project is look like now you can see at the screenshot. And my gradle build file is listed below. The problem is not solved even after clicking update project in jetgradle. And I should notice that it is not android studio but clean IDEA 12.1.6

```
apply plugin: 'java'


allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':opp-client')
}

project(':opp-client') {

    apply plugin: 'android'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/dahlgren/vpi-aar/raw/master"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
        compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:5.8'
        compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
        // compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
        compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
        // provided 'com.github.rchugunov:android:4.2-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'com.github.rchugunov:android-support-v4:r18-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'com.github.rchugunov:google-analytics:2.0-beta5-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'com.github.rchugunov:flurry:3.2.2-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'com.github.rchugunov:parse:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'com.github.rchugunov:list-view-animations:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'com.github.rchugunov:appcompat-v7:r19-SNAPSHOT@aar'
        compile 'com.github.rchugunov:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
        compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 18
        buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: idea sccreenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Gradle support in IntelliJ 12 is limited, and most people use Gradle's "idea" plugin to generate IntelliJ project files, rather than using IntelliJ's "JetGradle" plugin. I don't know how well that works for Android projects, though. IntelliJ 13 (EAP) and Android Studio (which is based on IntelliJ 13) have much better Gradle support.